# PowerShell Initiated Excel VBA Macro not doing anything

Tags: excel, vba, powershell

I have a working VBA Macro with working Data in an Excel. Probably some of you wan't to see that Macro but trust me it works. It worked for multiple weeks and if I open the File PowerShell is going to edit and click on the Button the Macro works as well, so no Problem there.

For the start my PowerShell Script should just execute the macro and save the Excel.
I Found out how you run macros / click a button and how to save the File. Here's my Code:

```bsh
$ExcelPath = "PathToMyExcel"

$excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($ExcelPath)

$excel.Visible = $true
$app = $excel.Application
$app.Run("Sheet.Macro")
Start-Sleep -Seconds 2 # -> Just so I can see what the Macro "Should" be doing
$excel.Visible = $false

$workbook.Saved = $true
$workbook.SaveAs($ExcelPath)
$xl.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($xl)
[System.GC]::Collect()
```

My first Problem was that it didn't find and couldn't run the Macro, so I activated macros from the getgo and later found out that I had to include the sheet name my Button / Macro was in (Sheet.Macro).

I tried changing up the $app.Run("") with everything, Sheet, Workbook, Whole Excel Path and others, everyone gives me back an Error that It couldn't find the Macro but not the "Sheet.Macro" which gives back no Errors but, like I already said, doesn't do anything.

So, now I don't have any Errors it should work, but it doesn't. Is it because it's a VBA Macro or something different?

Comment: Try $app.run("workbookName.Macro")

Comment: as others have mentioned ... shouldn't this >>> `$xl.Visible` <<< be >>> `$excel.Visible` <<< instead?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey was just a spelling mistake I did in this example but thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @f6a4 Also didn't work.

Comment: Where do you have the macro defined? Is it added under Sheet1? If yes, you may need to do `$app.Run("Sheet1.Macro")`. Also, is `Macro` a `public sub Macro`?

Comment: @shahkalpesh It was "Sheet1.Macro", or for me "Tabelle1.Macro" because German and Excel taking the Language but thank you alot.
Can you Post it, then I could make it the Accepted answer if other People have that problem for later.

Comment: @TheLinkedOne - ah! typing errors [*grin*] ... glad to see that you found the actual problem & the fix! [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ExcelPath = "PathToMyExcel"

$excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($ExcelPath)

$excel.Visible = $true
$app = $excel.Application
$app.Run("Sheet1.Macro")
Start-Sleep -Seconds 2 # -> Just so I can see what the Macro "Should" be doing
$excel.Visible = $false

$workbook.Saved = $true
$workbook.SaveAs($ExcelPath)
$excel.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel)
[System.GC]::Collect()
```

Make sure you have the sheet name right.

I am assuming it should be `Sheet1` and the macro should be a `public sub` under `Sheet1'.